# Nginx dropping SSL handshakes with multiple virtual hosts

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have an Nginx server set up on an Ubuntu VPS with multiple hosts (1 IP).  Previously, 1 host had certificates set up and NO redirecting (http allowed) and 1 host had certificates and forced HTTPS via 301.  Now that I am attempting to force all of my hosts on SSL and force HTTPS, I am seeing that Nginx is dropping handshakes when I have more than 1 vhost with 301 directives.  In particular, the error I am seeing is:

`[error] 12370#0: *30 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: (removed), server: 0.0.0.0:443`

The issue definitely seems to be with my 301's, because if I exclude them I do not have an issue.  What's the best way I can force HTTPS and non-www in my server blocks?

All of my vhosts are in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, along with `ssl.conf` (listed below).  I can provide `nginx.conf` if requested, but I didn't see anything that would seem useful in there.

**`example1.conf`**

```
server {
    server_name www.example1.com example1.com;
    return 301 https://example1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    server_name www.example1.com
    return 301 https://example1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example1.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/example1.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example1.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example1.com.error.log;
}
```

**`example2.conf`**
same as `example1.conf` (except with example2.com instead of example1.com)

**`ssl.conf`**

```
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;

# Perfect Forward Security
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS +RC4 RC4";

# HSTS
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
```

Pointing out other obvious errors is also appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using `error_page 497 https://$host$request_uri;` within your one true ssl server block instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved (at least for now) by removing

```
server {  
    listen 443;

    server_name www.example1.com
    return 301 https://example1.com$request_uri;
}
```

It seems that since there's no cert specified, this block would get hit for all HTTPS requests and then the connection would get dropped.